# Adding custom suggestions to Windows Phone keyboard Word Flow

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, keyboard-events

I want to add some custom controls to the word flow just like the 6tag app

[image: custom controls]

Any hint is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone doesn't support adding custom dictionaries or responses to the soft keyboard itself.

What you can do is add your own control above (but outside) the soft keyboard to display your own suggestions. The app can handle the InputPane.[Showing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.viewmanagement.inputpane.showing.aspx) event to find the location of the input pane so the app can place its controls just outside the [occluded rectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.viewmanagement.inputpane.occludedrect.aspx).